# Outlook Sorting Emails Based on first letter

Tags: vba, sorting, vbscript, outlook, string-search

I have a user that wants to sort incoming emails based on the sender's first letter in their email address. I found some things in other questions but I am having trouble actually sorting based on their email address.

```
Sub FilterTest()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim MyFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim SenderName As String

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olInbox = Application.Session.Folders("me@company.com").Folders("Inbox")
Set MyFolder = Nothing

For i = olInbox.Items.Count To olInbox.Items.Count Step -1
    olInbox.Items.Item (i)
    SenderName = (olInbox.Items.Item(i).SenderEmailAddress)


        If SenderName Like "a*" Or SenderName Like "b*" Or SenderName Like "c*" Or SenderName Like "d*" Or SenderName Like "e*" Or SenderName Like "f*" Or SenderName Like "g*" Then
            MsgBox ("From a-g")
            Set MyFolder = Application.Session.Folders("me@company.com").Folders("test")
        End If
        If SenderName Like "h*" Or SenderName Like "i*" Or SenderName Like "j*" Or SenderName Like "k*" Or SenderName Like "l*" Or SenderName Like "m*" Or SenderName Like "n*" Or SenderName Like "o*" Then
            MsgBox ("From h-o")
            Set MyFolder = Application.Session.Folders("me@company.com").Folders("test 2")
        End If
        If SenderName Like "p*" Or SenderName Like "q*" Or SenderName Like "r*" Or SenderName Like "s*" Or SenderName Like "t*" Or SenderName Like "u*" Or SenderName Like "v*" Or SenderName Like "w*" Or SenderName Like "x*" Or SenderName Like "y*" Or SenderName Like "z*" Then
            MsgBox ("From p-z")
            Set MyFolder = Application.Session.Folders("me@company.com").Folders("test 3")
        End If

        If MyFolder Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "This folder doesn't exist!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "INVALID FOLDER"
        Else
            olInbox.Items.Item(i).Move MyFolder
        End If
Next
End Sub
```

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this but I'm getting nothing...
It never goes into any of the if statements.

Anyone know how I can make this code work?
Or maybe another way to sort based on the first letter of an email address?

Comment: Can't you just right-click the header of the email list ("From | Subject", etc.), then select "View Settings", then click the "Sort..." button, and from there chose "To" from the list of Sort Items? I don't know what version of Outlook, but on mine it has this option. It is the Office 2010 Outlook (actual Outlook version 14.0.xxxx).

Comment: I read the code and it seems you want to sort them into specific folders. My previous comment would be unhelpful.

Comment: you can use a combination of ucase and asc(<char>) to get the numerical value and implement a greater then - less then comparision to sort which would eliminate the need for the like clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is an example how you can make it a bit more readable

also if oyu use SmtpAddress you shouldnt have to worry about the x400 stuff

```
SenderName = (olInbox.Items.Item(i).SmtpAddress)

    'A = 65
    'G = 71
    'H = 72
    'O = 79
    'P = 80
    'Z = 90
    Dim numericLetterValue As Integer

    numericLetterValue = Asc(UCase(Left(SenderName, 1)))
    If numericLetterValue > 64 And numericLetterValue < 72 Then
        MsgBox ("From a-g")
        Set MyFolder = Application.Session.Folders("me@company.com").Folders("test")
    ElseIf numericLetterValue > 71 And numericLetterValue < 80 Then
        MsgBox ("From h-o")
        Set MyFolder = Application.Session.Folders("me@company.com").Folders("test 2")
    ElseIf numericLetterValue > 79 And numericLetterValue < 91 Then
        MsgBox ("From p-z")
        Set MyFolder = Application.Session.Folders("me@company.com").Folders("test 3")
    ElseIf MyFolder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "This folder doesn't exist!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "INVALID FOLDER"
    Else
        olInbox.Items.Item(i).Move MyFolder
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the issue is only with internal emails because the email address comes in as the x400 address rather than the normal name@company.com so it's going to take a little more parsing

In other words, this script works for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you can shift the groups a bit, you can compute the index into an array of folder names:

```
>> aMap = Array("AH", "IP", "QZ", "QZ")
>> For nFL = Asc("A") To Asc("Z")
>>     WScript.Echo Chr(nFL), aMap((nFL - Asc("A"))\8)
>> Next
>>
A AH
B AH
C AH
D AH
E AH
F AH
G AH
H AH
I IP
J IP
K IP
L IP
M IP
N IP
O IP
P IP
Q QZ
R QZ
S QZ
T QZ
U QZ
V QZ
W QZ
X QZ
Y QZ
Z QZ
>>
```